# What is window.parent.parent

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window

Ok so I saw a piece of interesting code when I translated youtube from english to french in google translate ( see below ). I just want to know what it means.

What does `window.parent.parent` mean and in what cases does `if(window.parent.parent==window.top){return true}else{return false}`return true ( and the contrary)?
I know `window.top` but i'm not sure about `window.parent` or `window.parent.parent`.
TIA

Comment: window.parent is the parent window ... so window.parent.parent is the parent window's parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a iframe for example window.parent refers to the window above the iframe.
Top refers to the top most window.

When there are no parents, window.parent refers to window itself...
parent property is never null